# Angular Material Wrapper class giving error

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to create a component that essentially wraps mat-expansion-panel.
See code at:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-4wcj9i

But it is giving me "No provider for MatExpansionPanel"
despite me specifying viewProviders: [MatExpansionPanel]
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any errors showing up in your example, and it's not clear which component you're having trouble with. Could you specify what file or where the problem is?

Comment: Apologies - I managed to get rid of the error message itself just after posting the Q.
However the problem itself is that the component should be an expansion panel with a header (Personal data , Type your name and age ) and details that appear when the header is clicked (hello world)
I've updated the example which now shows the 'correct' component, using 'pure' mat- components

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the initial issue by adding

viewProviders: [MatExpansionPanel]

to the expansion-panel-header.component.ts

There is still an issue but I will post a separate question for this.